# how to convert one-hot vectors to multi-label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow

I have a multi-classification task, and I have gotten the one-hot type predictions like

```
[[0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1]]
```

I wish to convert this one-hot vector to labels like

```
[[1, 2], [1], [0, 2]]
```

I have tried tf.argmax, but it doesn't work. So how can I deal with it?

Comment: These aren't "one-hot"; that requires that only one value can be equal to `1` in a given row.

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehensions:

```
oheList = [[0, 1, 1],
           [0, 1, 0],
           [1, 0, 1]]
[[i for i in range(len(el)) if el[i]==1] for el in oheList]
# [[1, 2], [1], [0, 2]]
```

Comment: how to achieve it with tensorflow?

Comment: You mean your output is a tensor? Convert it to numpy then to a list. Without your code to output the prediction it's difficult to tell but try `oheList = list(predictionOutput.numpy())` and then run the list comprehension code

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve the problem,

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0, 1, 1],
                [0, 1, 0],
                [1, 0, 1]])

result = {}
for r, c in zip(*np.where(arr == 1)):
    result.setdefault(r, []).append(c)

print(result.values())
```

```
[[1, 2], [1], [0, 2]]
```